# Outlook 2010 AppointmentItem.GetOrganizer and ResponseStatus access violation

Tags: c++, crash, outlook

Developing a plugin which syncs events in Outlook with an external system.

However, Outlook often crashes at lines like:

```
m_Event->get_ResponseStatus( &olAppointmentResponseStatus );
```

or
    m_Event->GetOrganizer( &spAddrEntry );

For the same event, one run it works and another run it crashes, no predictable pattern here.

At the same time, other properties are working fine, like this:

```
m_Event->get_ReminderSet( &bReminderSet );
```

m_Event is declared as:
CComPtr m_Event;

Looks like the problem occurs when the event is not absolutely correct, such as when its organizer status is unknown. I think I would be able to deal with (or even fix) such events it I Outlook hadn't crashed.

Obviously, try catch (...) does not help as access violation is not C++ exception. Is there any way to make Outlook not crash when reading event properties? Maybe, some kind of "enable safe mode", or whatever..

Another question why bad events appear there at all as my plugin only creates events via Outlook API (does it mean Outlook can save an event which it cannot then read without crash?) but ideally I would want to deal with any events it may encounter in Outlook database.